My regex for a VS Code Snippet is not working
I have some files with names starting with core- and following one or more words separated by hyphen, like this:
core-query
core-query-pagination
core-query-pagination-numbers

I'm creating a VS Code Snippet to transform the file name to get this result:
QUERY
QUERY PAGINATION
QUERY PAGINATION NUMBERS


Remove core-
Replace - with  
Capitalize every word

What I've got so far is this:
"${TM_FILENAME_BASE/([^-]+)(-*)/${1:/capitalize}${2:+ }/g}"

Output:
Core Query Pagination Numbers


Please check if the following works for you:
${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/(^core-)|(-)|([a-z]*)/${2:+ }${3:/upcase}/gm}

You can use the following if you do not need to remove the -.
${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/^core-(.*)/${1:/upcase}/gm}


This works! Thank you very much! I just tweaked it a bit to get exactly what I was looking for: ${TM_FILENAME_BASE/(^core-)|(-)|([a-zA-Z]+)/${2:+ }${3:/capitalize}/gi}.
